# Inform child component about data update in Angular 2

Tags: angular

In my Angular 2 app I have one main component that has a certain child component (named SystemDynamicsComponent in particular) embedded.

I include this child component in the parent component as follows:

```
<system-dynamics [sdFactors]="displayedCalculation?.getCombinedSdFactors()"></system-dynamics>
```

The interesting part is the parameter `sdFactors` which is passed to the child component. Inside the child component it is defined as follows:

```
@Input() sdFactors: any[] = [];
```

Summarized, the parent component passes data to the child component like above.

The point is that the parent component obtains the data asynchronously over HTTP using a Promise. For some reason I want to inform the child component once this data is completely retrieved.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add getter and setter for this :

```
private _sdFactors: any[] = [];

@Input() 
public set sdFactor(value: any[]) {
    // sdFactor updated ! you can do something
    this._sdFactor = value;
}

public get sdFactor(): any[] {
    return this._sdFactor;
}
```